# vb.net Excel and NumberFormat for Currency

Tags: excel, vb.net, currency, number-formatting

I am trying to progamatically set an Excel column to type Currency

Hi,

I am using a vb.net application to get data from a database and put it in an Excel worksheet.

In the vb.net code, I'm doing:-

I'm selecting the cell into which I wish to put the data, setting the numberformat to "£#,##0.00", then putting the value in e.g. £200.00

When I subsequently open the Excel workbook, the value correctly appears as e.g. £200.00
but on the Home tab, in the  Number section, the dropdown box says 'Custom'

Is there a way to definitively make the column type 'Currency' please?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Are pounds your regional currency?

Answer (score 1):

If you manually set a cell to Currency and then would read it's numberformat in VBA, you'd receive something like `$#,##0_);[Red]($#,##0)`

To showcase the differences:

```
Sub exampleFormat()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Me.Range("A5")
    rng.NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);[Red]($#,##0)"
    rng.Value = 300 'will show as (regional) Currency
    Set rng = Me.Range("B5")
    rng.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    rng.Value = 400 'will show as (regional currency but) Custom format
    Set rng = Me.Range("C5")
    rng.NumberFormat = "£#,##0_);[Red]($#,##0)"
    rng.Value = 300 'will show as Custom format regardless
    Set rng = Me.Range("D5")
    rng.NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"
    rng.Value = 400 'will show as Custom format as well
End Sub
```

I know I said VBA but I haven't read anything contradicting VB.NET being different, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think this is more about the actual property value in the format vs the particular flavor of VB involved in setting it.

Comment: I've made slight errors prior trying to answer VB.NET questions with VBA-code so I double-checked but figured I could still be wrong in the end :p @Craig

Comment: Thanks for your example. I tried it in VBA in Excel and the first two showed as type Currency in the Dropdown box and the last two as Custom.
However, when I tried it in vb.net, I'm still getting Custom in the Dropdown box.

Answer (score 0):

I did what you suggested and manually set a cell to Currency and then read its numberformat in vb.net.

```
 It came out as "$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)".

However, using that to put the value into Excel, as in my original post, still resulted in 'Custom' being displayed in the dropdown box in the Home tab, in the Number section.

I really don't know what else I can try. 

Thanks,

Kevin
```